# get all rows of column with datatype bit

Tags: c#, sql-server

i need to pass a parameter to stored procedure to get all rows which data type of column is Bit .
example :

```
select * from user where active = true   // get all actived users 
select * from user where active = false   // get all Not actived users
```

what can i do when i need to get all rows . i pass the active value as a parameter from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `?` to nullify your C# `bool` value:

```
bool? showActive = SomeCode();
```

Pass the potentially null `showActive` flag and update your SQL code with this:

```
select * from user where active = @showActive or @showActive is null
```

If the `@showActive` parameter passed is null, all rows will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the active parameter optional, and do something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers](
    @Active BIT = NULL
) AS

BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM user
    WHERE (@Active IS NULL OR active = @Active)

END
```

And in the code, add an overloaded fetch method:

```
var users = GetUsers(true); //pass active as true

var users = GetUsers(); //dont pass active parameter, return all users
```

Comment: Use this answer and specify `null` as parameter value if you want to get all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what data is in active column.
If you have true and false, which I doubt, becuase sql db doesn`t support these kind of value tyes, but you at least can have bit value type. So bit can have only 1 or 0 (one or zero).

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved like:

```
WHERE user.active = ISNULL(@Active, user.active)
```

using this, SQL server can use an index if one is available and can be used.

Comment: Have you tried this? SQL Server only seems to use an index with `column = ISNULL(@var, constant)`, not `column = ISNULL(@var, column)`.

Answer (score 0):

I like something like this. Given a stored procedure :

```
create procedure dbo.SelectAccounts

  @fExpired bit

as

  set ansi_nulls              on
  set concat_null_yields_null on

  select *
  from dbo.Account acct
  where acct.Expired = @fExpired = coalesce( @fExpired , acct.Expired )
  -- a more verbose alternative test
  --    (          acct.Expired =  @fExpired
  --      OR (     acct.Expired is null
  --           and @fExpired    is not null
  --         )
  --    )

  return 0 

go
```

I generate a class that looks something like this:

```
public class dbo_SelectAccounts
{
  public const string STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME = @"dbo.SelectAccounts";

  private string   ConnectString    { get ;         set ; }
  public int       ReturnCode       { get ; private set ; }
  public int       TimeoutInSeconds { get ; private set ; }
  public DataTable ResultSet        { get ; private set ; }
  public int       RowCount         { get { return this.ResultSet.Rows.Count ; } }

  public int Exec( bool? @fExpired )
  {
    using ( SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection( this.ConnectString ) )
    using ( SqlCommand     cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
    using ( SqlDataAdapter sda  = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
    {

      cmd.CommandText    = STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME;
      cmd.CommandType    = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandTimeout = this.TimeoutInSeconds ;

      // 1. Format parameter to stored procedure
      SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter( @"@fExpired" , SqlDbType.Bit ) ;
      if ( @fExpired == null )
      {
        p1.Value = System.DBNull.Value ;
      }
      else
      {
        p1.Value = @fExpired ;
      }
      cmd.Parameters.Add( p1 );

      // add return code parameter
      SqlParameter pReturnCode = new SqlParameter();
      pReturnCode.SqlDbType    = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
      pReturnCode.Direction    = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
      cmd.Parameters.Add( pReturnCode );

      conn.Open();
      sda.Fill( this.ResultSet ) ;
      conn.Close();

      this.ReturnCode = (int)pReturnCode.Value;

    }

    return this.ReturnCode;
  }

  #region constructors

  public dbo_SelectAccounts( string connectionString , int executionTimeoutInSeconds )
  {
    this.ConnectString    = connectionString          ;
    this.TimeoutInSeconds = executionTimeoutInSeconds ;
    this.ReturnCode       = -1                        ;
    this.ResultSet        = new DataTable()           ;
    return ;
  }

  public dbo_SelectAccounts( string connectionString )
  : this( connectionString , 30 )
  {
    this.ConnectString = connectionString;
  }

  public dbo_SelectAccounts( SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb , int executionTimeoutInSeconds )
  : this( csb.ConnectionString , executionTimeoutInSeconds )
  {
    return;
  }

  public dbo_SelectAccounts( SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb )
  : this( csb.ConnectionString )
  {
    return;
  }

  #endregion constructors

}
```

Usage is simple:

```
dbo_SelectAccount sp = new dbo_SelectAccounts( myConnectString ) ;
int               rc = sp.Exec( null ) ;
```